# How to manually audit log in django-auditlog

Tags: python, django, django-auditlog

How do you manually audit log in django-auditlog? There is no example in the documentation and there is still very limited sources about this. Should the model be registered? What i am really trying to achieve is to manually log data so that i can add additional data like remarks. But i am having problems in using the LogEntry.objects.log_create().

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

first import `LogEntry` model from auditlog package:

```
from auditlog.models import LogEntry
```

second add you custom log with fields used below:

```
my_object = MyModel.objects.get(id=object_id)

LogEntry.objects.create(
            actor_id=request.user.id,
            content_type_id=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(my_object).pk,
            object_id=object_id,
            object_pk=object_id,
            object_repr=str(my_object),
            action=1,  # 0 for create, 1 for update, 2 for delete
            changes=json.dumps({
                "field_name1": ["from_value", "to_value"],
                "field_name2": ["from_value", "to_value"]
            }),
)
```